# Matrix Invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If $A^2 = 0$, then show that $I-A$ is invertible.

I approached this problem using a constructive proof, however, I am getting no where that leads me to $I+A$.

Comment: $(I-A)(I+A)=I-A^2$

Answer (score 5):

Since $(I + A)(I - A) = I - A^2 = I$, $I - A$ is invertible with inverse $I + A$.

The heuristic idea is to consider the series

$$(1 + x)^{-1} = 1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + \cdots$$

If you "substitute" $A$ for $x$ and let $I$ act as $1$, you'll get

$$(I + A)^{-1} = I + A + A^2 + A^3 + \cdots$$

Since $A^2 = 0$, $A^k = 0$ for all $k \ge 2$. So

$$(I + A)^{-1} = I + A$$

So a natural candidate for the inverse of $I - A$ is $I + A$.